# Create endtime from collection_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Good Afternoon,

Feels like a newbie question but I have the following:

```
:start_datetime t.date
:end_datetime t.date
:length t.integer
```

On create my end_datetime is nil but I want to get it by adding the length to the start_datetime in order to generate the endtime.

Currently my integer is stored as '30 Mins', 30 and '1 Hour', 60.

Drawn a blank on where I should do this. I'm guessing I need to create it in the model when the booking is created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're going to be using increments of minutes, I think you should start by redefining your datetimes as `datetime` rather than `date`.

then do something like this:

```
#controller

def create
  ...
  end_datetime = params[:start_datetime] + params[:length].minutes
  #save this
  ...
end
```